# I was trying to make side navigation bar open with a checkbox but when I check the box the side bar doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, html, css

Any ideas where I went wrong? I have tried setting width to 0 inside CSS and using JavaScript to add width it still didn't work.

```js
 
 function showsidenav(){
      document.getElementsById("barres").style.display = "block"; 
   }
```

```css
.opened-side-nav {
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border-right: black 2px solid;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
 }
```

```html
<!--Nav Bar-->
<div class="opened-side-nav" id="barres">Content</div>
    <div class="logo">
        <input  id="5055" class="showsidenavbar" type="checkbox" onclick="showsidenav()">
        <label for="5055">=</label> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mary's answer is correct, remove the s from the getElementsById, OP I recommend that you get an IDE or an extension for code auto-completion if you are not much experienced, and on a side note, that's a very weird looking navbar, why does it cover the entire page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getElementById` and not `getElementsById`. For id, there's no 's' in Element. The 's' in the spelling is causing it, that is if your code is working fine.